# How to add explanation/description for a newly defined label in SpaCy's NER?

Tags: nlp, spacy, named-entity-recognition

I'm creating a new label called GADGET to identify gadgets like Apple iPhone, Samsung TV etc. How do I add a custom description for the new label ?

For example, if label='ORG' & we give spacy.explain(label), it gives a description for ORG. How can I add similarly for a new label?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the spacy model in your project and you can find **glossary.py** file `spaCy/spacy/glossary.py` there You can define your label and save it. Then You can get explanation of your label using `spacy.explain(label)`

Answer (score 0):

You can update the spacy [glossary file](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/glossary.py) available in your site-packages path.

I hope this helps!